# Render HTML pages from private folder in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a web site that have HTML pages stored in a private folder. I want a PHP script that can read the HTML file then push it to the browser.

My tought was to get the html file with the `file()` function in PHP. Then `echo()` it to the browser. That works for the html content of the page. The images and the css does not follow however.

I heard of a "render" function in IIS or ASP that render the HTML content of a web page in a private folder then send the images in a binary format. **Does PHP have something similar?**

Currently I read the file as follow :

```
$htmlFile = file(PATHTOFILE);
echo(implode('',$htmlFile));
```

The reason we are trying to do that is to protect the url / information of the pages contained in this folder. The user will have to connect to the web service, then the PHP script will push the html pages

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but an alternative would be to put the JS and the CSS into the header of the file that you're pulling.  Save your HTML files w/o the doctype, html or head tags, then in the PHP, build the HTML output.  Add your html tags, your css, js, etc.  Just a thought.

Comment: If the images and CSS are also in a private folder, then those will need to be pushed out to the user agent when the user agent requests them. You could use mod_rewrite to accomplish this (have your script handle all requests for .html, .css, .js, .png, .jpg, etc...)

Comment: What do you want this for? Are you trying to load a normal web page based on templates? If so, an image is a terrible choice for a number of reasons.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't store the content in a database? Does it need to be stored as flat files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the tag `base` to solve the problem of the relative path of the files, something like this:

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$html = str_replace('<head>', '<head><base href="FULL PATH OF DIR" />', $html);
echo $html;
```

Comment: sorry, now I read the reason. but, if you need protect some informations, what do you think protect only files that need protection, as files like css, js and images are public?

Answer (score 0):

CSS and images are not displayed because their paths in the HTML files is relative to HTML files, right? And if you have these CSS and images in the same private folder, how can you hope the user will fetch them?

Indirect, you should fetch CSS and images the same way you do with HTML. But this means you have to replace all paths in your displayed HTML, that is quite absurd. In fact, we are talking about some kind of proxy now... ?!?!?

Why you need it?

Anyway `echo(file_get_contents($htmlFile));` is less stressful.

Answer (score 0):

Another option if it is an `<img />` tag and the image is also stored outside of the root you can just make the `src=` attribute as so:

`src="get_image.php?file=thisfile.png" // add a $_GET if needed to distinguish files`

then get_image.php:

```
  $file = $_GET['file'];

  // security checks if you wish

  header(sprintf("Content-type: %s;",'image/png'));
  readfile($file);
  exit;
```